AWS RDS: does promoting a Read replica break replication to its own replica?
I have setup a primary DB (say, instance A1) and a read-replica (A2) in region A. Now I'm making the same setup in region B (so a primary DB B1 and a read-replica B2 that replicates it).
The second region is for disaster recovery (not for High Availability), currently B1 is replicating A1 as well and not serving Write request. Questions:

Can I setup B2 as a read-replica of a read-replicate (B1)?
In DR scenario, region A goes down, I'll promote B1 as the primary Read-Write replica. Does this break the replication B1-B2 ? I.e, after promoting B1, is there anything for me to do regarding B2 instance?

Thanks in advance!
